# MIFARE desfire EV1 communication using winscard

Tags: authentication, smartcard, mifare, apdu, winscard

I need some help communicating with Desfire EV1 card. The library (winscard.dll) seems to be automatically handling all responses from the card that have an ADDITIONAL_FRAME (AF) byte so that the application receives already processed data. For example, I send the GetVersion command as follows:

> > [out] 90 60 00 00 00, and the response is:
> >       [ in ] 04 01 01 01 00 18 05 04 01 01 01 04 18 05 04 83 71 2A 9F 43 80 BA 64 17 8F A0 07 15 **91 00**

Note: *I wrapped the command data in ISO 7816 headers*.

I expected the communication to be something like this:

> > [out] 90 60 00 00 00
> >      [ in ] 04 01 01 01 00 18 05 **91 AF**
> >
> > [out] 90 AF 00 00 00
> >     [ in ] 04 01 01 01 04 18 05 **91 AF**
> >
> > [out] 90 AF 00 00 00
> >     [ in ] 04 83 71 2A 9F 43 80 BA 64 17 8F A0 07 15 **91 00**.

The same thing happens during card authentication so when I send

> > [out] 90 0A 00 00 01 00 00, I get back
> >      [ in ] 91 00
> >     instead of a card challenge.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: I have seen a reader doing the ANOTHER FRAME automagically (maybe Omnikey, not sure)....but not for the authentication (even stranger is that the reader succeeds -- are you authenticated to the card after this command?)

Comment: Yes I am. I get authenticated to new cards and I can even create applications, but not to any card whose keys I have changed myself. I'm assuming it's because new cards have default keys of all 0's. So I guess the reader stores the keys somewhere and does the authentication itself. Maybe now I should find a way to communicate the keys to the reader and then send the authenticate command and see what happens.

Comment: Interesting, I would recommend to check the reader documentation regarding DESFire cards. Quite often the PC/SC command `Load keys` is used to store keys into the reader (see PC/SC, part 3, section 3.2.2.1.4 [here](http://www.pcscworkgroup.com/specifications/files/pcsc3_v2.01.09.pdf)). But these keys are usually used with the associated storage card functionality commands. Good Luck and please let us know about your results!

Comment: What reader are you using? Have you tried a different one?

Comment: I am using an Elyctis Reader that has been embedded within an Evolis printer.
According to the documentation I am supposed to load keys to the reader's EEPROM in this format: 
**FF 00 00 00 1F 07 01 PCDKeyNo AID PICCKeyNo Key1 Key2 Key3**
This works well, however I can't figure out how the printer performs card authentication as the document does not talk about it. I have tried various combinations to no avail.